# Terraform Error: Failed to install provider Error while installing <modulename> cannot install existing

Tags: terraform, aws-codebuild, terragrunt

I have been trying to run multiple terragrunt modules using AWS codebuild

module-a
module-b
module-v

I am running all of them sequentially as these have some dependencies
All of them have some common plugins and therefore I dont want to bloat the disk by downloading terraform separately . So I decided to installed them all in one folder by running

```
export TF_PLUGIN_CACHE_DIR=/root/.terraform.d/plugins
```

and specify this folder in buildspec.yaml of codebuild

```
cache:
  paths:
    -  /root/.terraform.d/plugins/
    -  /root/.terraform.d/plugins/**/*
```

However after doing that I am facing below errors

```
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing gavinbunney/kubectl v1.14.0: cannot install existing
│ provider directory
│ /root/.terraform.d/plugins/registry.terraform.io/gavinbunney/kubectl/1.14.0/linux_amd64
│ to itself
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing hashicorp/aws v4.67.0: cannot install existing
│ provider directory
│ /root/.terraform.d/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.67.0/linux_amd64
│ to itself
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing hashicorp/helm v2.10.1: cannot install existing
│ provider directory
│ /root/.terraform.d/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm/2.10.1/linux_amd64
│ to itself
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing hashicorp/kubernetes v2.21.1: cannot install
│ existing provider directory
│ /root/.terraform.d/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes/2.21.1/linux_amd64
│ to itself
╵
```

Can someone please help. What I want essentially is

- All terragrunt modules should use same plugins directory

Versions -
Terraform v1.5.0
terragrunt version v0.47.0

I tried choosing a different plugins directory but it wasnt getting used at all by terragrunt